# CSS Grid on static site that uses svg images is not responsive on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-grid, gsap

I am new to CSS Grid and I am having troubles with responsiveness. The columns are not stacking vertically on mobile devices.

I am using `display:grid` for a wrapping div called **"primary-wrapper"** and then child elements use `header`, `main`, `aside`, and `footer`. Then, I use `display:flex` for **grandchildren**.

The header has 3 columns: `#logo`, `.classic-menu (flexnav)`, and `#burger` wrapper for the mobile hamburger.

```js
// JavaScript to refresh when changing orientation
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (event) {
    location.reload(true);
});
```

```css
.primary-wrapper {grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 350px) 1fr 1fr; grid-template-rows: 75px 1fr 50px; grid-gap: 20px 30px}
header {grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;}
#logo {grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;}
.classic-menu {display:flex; justify-content: flex-start}
#burger-wrapper {grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;}
main {grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3; margin-left: 20px;}
aside {grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;}
footer {grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 4;}

/* mobile menu */
#menu-burger{right:20px}
.flexnav{padding:0 20px}
.destory{display:none}
#burger-wrapper {width:80px; height:80px; float:right; top:0;right:-25px; display:flex; justify-content:center;align-items:center; cursor:pointer}
.classic-menu #burger-wrapper {display:none}
#menu-burger{width:26px;height:32px;position:relative;margin:0 auto;z-index:20}
#burger-wrapper .touch-button{display:none}
.menu-overlay #menu-burger{display:block}
#menu-burger span {display:block; position:absolute; height:2px;width:100%; background-color:#fff;opacity:1;right:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);-o-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg);-webkit-transition:background-color .05s ease-in-out,transform .2s ease-in-out,top .2s ease-in-out;transition:background-color .05s ease-in-out,transform .2s ease-in-out,top .2s ease-in-out}

#menu-burger span:nth-child(1){top:7px}
#menu-burger span:nth-child(2){top:15px}
#menu-burger.open span:nth-child(1){-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg);top:10px}
#menu-burger.open span:nth-child(2){-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg);top:10px}
#menu-burger.open span:nth-child(3){display:none}


/*--------- flex nav flexnav ------*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
#menu-burger {display:block;position:absolute;right:50px;top:32px}
/*#menu-burger span.touch-button{display:none}*/
#burger-wrapper{right:2px;top:-4px}
.classic-menu #burger-wrapper {display:block}
.flexnav {padding:0 50px;background:transparent;-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;transition:all .5s ease-in-out}
.flexnav li {text-align:center;list-style-type:none;line-height:6vw;-webkit-transition:color .15s ease-out 0;transition:color .15s ease-out 0}

.nav-height {overflow-y:scroll;position:relative;height:100%;padding:40px 0; padding-right:30px; width:calc(100% + 30px);box-sizing:border-box}
nav {height:100vh;position:fixed;top:70px;left:0;z-index:99;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;visibility:visible; opacity:0;padding:20px 0;background-color:#0f1010}
nav.open {visibility:visible;pointer-events:initial;opacity:1}
.flexnav {max-height:2000px;-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in .6s; transition:all .4s ease-in .6s}
.flexnav.flexnav-show {-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-out .2s;transition:all .4s ease-out .2s}
.flexnav:hover li{color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4)}
.flexnav li:hover{color:rgba(255,255,255,1)}
.flexnav .touch-button{width:100%;display:block;height:calc(6vw + 20px)}
.flexnav .touch-button .navicon{display:none}
.flexnav li.link{border-bottom:none}
.flexnav li a{font-weight:700;font-family:'Poppins',sans-serif;font-size:6vw;padding:10px 0;color:#ffffff;display:block}

.flexnav li ul{margin-bottom:20px}
.flexnav li ul:after{display:none}
.flexnav li ul li a{padding:10px 0;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:20px;border-top:none}
}

@media all and (min-width: 1025px) {
nav {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 30%; display:block; z-index: 999;}
.classic-menu nav {width:auto;text-align:right;height:40px;margin:10px 0;background-color:transparent!important; opacity: 1;}
.classic-menu #burger-wrapper {display: none;}
.flexnav{display:inline-flex;width:auto;max-height:40px}
.flexnav li{color:#fff}
.flexnav li ul{min-width:160px;background-color:rgb(149,237,142)}
.flexnav li > ul li:hover{background-color:rgba(149,237,142,0.7)}
.flexnav .touch-button {background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0}
.flexnav .touch-button .navicon {display:none}
.flexnav li{background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;padding:0 25px;list-style:none}
.menu-timeline{opacity:1}
.flexnav li:first-child{padding-left:0}
.flexnav li:last-child{padding-right:0}
.flexnav li a{background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;padding:10px 0 4px;position:relative;border-left:medium none;font-weight:600;font-family:'Poppins',sans-serif;color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);font-size:1.15em;line-height:20px;display:block;overflow:hidden}
.flexnav li.active a{color:#fff}

.flexnav li:hover a{color:#e9078a}
.flexnav li a span {position:relative;display:block;-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .2s;transition:transform .2s;transform-origin:100% 0}
.flexnav li a span::before{position:absolute;top:100%;width:100%;left:0;content:attr(data-hover)}
.navbar .flexnav .submenu ul{display:none}
.navbar .flexnav .submenu:hover ul{display:block}
.flexnav li:hover a span{-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%);transform-origin:0 0}
.flexnav li ul li a{padding:10px 20px;background-color:transparent;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;font-weight:600;text-transform:none;color:#fff!important;-webkit-transition:all .05s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .05s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .05s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all .05s ease-in-out;transition:all .05s ease-in-out}
.flexnav li ul li a.link::before{display:none}
.flexnav li ul li a.active,.flexnav li ul li a:hover{color:#fff!important}
.flexnav li > ul li{margin-left:0;padding:0;margin-bottom:0}
.flexnav li:first-child ul{left:-15px}
.flexnav li ul ul{left:5px!important}
.flexnav ul li ul li a{background:#000}
.flexnav li ul.flexnav-show{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px);transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px);opacity:1!important;visibility:visible;-webkit-transition:opacity .2s ease-in-out 0.1s,visibility .2s ease-in-out,transform .2s ease-in-out .1s;transition:opacity .2s ease-in-out 0.1s,visibility .2s ease-in-out,transform .2s ease-in-out .1s}
.flexnav .touch-button{display:none}
}

/* home page */
.xl4uhomeBlock h1:before {}
.contactXL4U-hero {vertical-align:middle;}
.contactXL4U-hero .ahhh {font-weight: 600; color: rgba(255,255,255,.85); font-size:48px;line-height:60px}
.contactXL4U-hero .ahhh span {color: #6780e4}
.homeProducts {color: #fff; opacity: 1;  font-size: 1.05em;  font-weight: 300;  line-height: 1.3em;  width: 100%;}
button[name="your-project"] {margin: 15px auto; width: 100%;}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
    .contactXL4U-hero .ahhh {margin-top: 20%;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>XLDesign4u in Richmond, VA</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="XLDesign4U description here" />
    <meta name="author" content="TriMedia Richmond, VA">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />    
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/css/blocks-xl4u.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<div class="grid primary-wrapper">
         <!-- Header -->
            <header class="grid classic-menu">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/index.php">
                        <img src="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/images/svg/XL-Designs-4U-logo.min.svg" alt="XLDesign4U Logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!--/Logo -->             
                
                <!-- Navigation -->
                <nav class="navbar" >            
                                <ul data-breakpoint="1025" class="flexnav">
                                    <li class="link menu-timeline active submenu"><a class="link" href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/xldesign-4U.php">Home</a>
                                    </li> 
                                    <li class="link menu-timeline"><a class="ajax-link link" data-type="page-transition" href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/about.php">About</a></li>
                                    <li class="link menu-timeline"><a class="ajax-link link" data-type="page-transition" href="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/contact-xl4u.php">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li class="link menu-timeline"><a class="ajax-link link" href="http://www.sgcontact.com/emails/nhmkizr/index.html" target="_blank" >News</a></li>
                                    <li class="link menu-timeline"><a class="ajax-link link" href="https://www.promoplace.com/xldesign4u/showrooms_001.htm" target="_blank">Client Login</a></li>
                                </ul>            
                                
                </nav>
                <!--/Navigation -->
                <!-- Menu Burger -->
                <div id="burger-wrapper">
                    <button id="menu-burger">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--/Menu Burger -->
            </header>
            <!--/Header -->        
            <main class="xl4uhomeBlock">       
        <div class="contactXL4U-hero">
                <div class="ahhh">Ahhhh! Relax.</div> 
                <h2>Discover our world of services here for a relaxing carefree experience.</h2>
                <p class="homeProducts">With over 300,000 products... we have everything from the unique to the fast value.</p>
                <button name="your-project" type="button" id="createAnimation"><a href="#tellus">Tell us about your project.</a></button>
</div>
 <a name="tellus"> </a>
             <div class="flex contactXL4U">
                         <div class="box-flex address left">
                              <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <h6>Address goes here</h6>
                       </div>
                        <div class="box-flex email left">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                             <h6><a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.org&subject=Inquiry%20from%20XL4U website&bcc=bcc@xxx@trimedia.co">E-mail XLDesign4U</a></h6>
                       </div>
                       <div class="box-flex fax">
                            <i class="fa fa-fax fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                 <h6>Fax xxx.xxx.xxxx</h6>
                        </div>
                          <div class="box-flex call">
                        <i class="fa fa-fax fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                         <h6><a href="tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx">Call xxx.xxx.xxxx</a></h6>
                            </div>
                        
                    
                       <button name="messageXL4u" type="button"><a href="#maincontactForm" id="onlineContactForm">Online Contact Form</a></button>
                       <a name="maincontactForm"> </a>
                      <!-- Contact Form -->
                      <div id="contact-formWrap">
                         <div id="message"> </div>
                          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                             <h6>Send us a message</h6>
                                    <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">                             
                                        <div class="name-box">        
                                            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Full Name') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Full Name'; }" value="Full Name" ><label class="input_label">What's Your Name?</label>
                                        </div>                                                        
                                        <div class="email-box">
                                            <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'E-mail') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'E-mail'; }" value="E-mail" >E-mail Address<label class="input_label"></label>
                                        </div>                            
                                        <div class="message-box">
                                            <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="4" id="comments" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your Message') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Your Message'; }" >Your Message</textarea><label class="input_label slow"></label>
                                        </div>                             
                                         <div class="submit-box">             
                                            <input type="submit" class="send_message clapat-button outline link" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                                        </div>
                                    </form>           
                                </div></div>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <div class="flower-wrapper">
         <img src="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/images/svg/hibiscus-Small.svg" alt="Hibiscus Flower"> 
    </div>
</div>  </aside>
    <footer>
                        <div class="socials-wrap">              
                        <div class="socials-icon"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        <div class="socials-text">Social Media &amp; Legal</div>
                        <ul class="socials">
                            <li><span class="parallax-wrap"><a class="parallax-element" href="https://www.facebook.com/XLDesign4U" target="_blank">Fb</a></span></li>
                            <li><span class="parallax-wrap"><a class="parallax-element" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xldesign4u/" target="_blank">In</a></span></li>
                            <li><span class="parallax-wrap"><a class="parallax-element" href="https://twitter.com/XLDesignLori" target="_blank">Tw</a></span></li>
                             <li><span class="parallax-wrap"><a class="parallax-element" href="https://www.pinterest.com/xl4u/xldesign4u/" target="_blank">Pn</a></span></li>
                             <li><span class="parallax-wrap"><a class="parallax-element copyright-icon" href="#copyright" target="_blank">&copy;</a></span></li>
                            <li><span class="parallax-wrap"><a class="parallax-element privacy-icon" href="#privacy-policy">Le</a></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
<div class="copyright-xl4u hidden"><a name="copyright"></a>Copyright XLDesign4U, 2020. All rights reserved.</div>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-APllMc0V4lf/Rb5Cz4idWUCYlBDG3b0EcN1Ushd3hpE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/js/contact-form.js"></script>
 <script src="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/js/xl4u.js"></script>
 <script src="https://trimedia.co/xl4u/gsap-animations.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a Codepen or Codesandbox link, please?

Comment: @sigfried Yes, I will make a codepen now and get back to you.

Comment: Good, not only for me :), if you ask a question and include a functional Proof of Concept people will, more likely, review your code. Thanks

Comment: I feel ya bro, I misunderstood the code snippet functionality in stackoverflow. 

Thanks for your help! Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/yayaCreates/pen/yLOWaWL

Comment: Thanks, what columns do you want to be vertically stacked? One thing to keep in mind while working with `CSS Grid` is that you're working in `two dimensions` (notice that you define both `columns` and `rows`, not only one as you do when working with `Flexbox`.

Comment: Good question. I want aside to stack under main, which is currently in the middle row.
Being a css-grid newbie, I don't know if I have the tracks properly configured.

Comment: Good, so, for the `grid-area` of the `aside` you should use: `grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 4;`. I tested that in FF Dev Tools (maybe the best tool to work with CSS Grid, Flexbox, you name it :D) and it worked as you asked, the `aside` is below the `main`. If this solves your problem let me know to post a proper answer with some helpful links. Cheers

Comment: Ah, I see the aside stacked under the main now on mobile. However, it is no longer on the right when in desktop view. ------- I agree! I have Firefox open with grid lines showing. Granted, I could use a media query; but avoided that since css-grid is supposed to save us from media query world.

Comment: I'm not sure about your latter point, true, CSS Grid help avoiding some media query stuff but not all of it I suppose :). This is a very good [CSS Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) also, the course from Scrimba is great. Cheers

Comment: Thank you @sigfried all of this information is very helpful. We are ready to mark as solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Nice design by the way! :). Cheers, sigfried

Comment: Thanks, Sigfried! I've added gsap animations to it on the test server.  Are you going to post the solution so that I can reward your efforts? :)

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind :), I'll elaborate the answer. Cheers, sigfried.

Comment: I added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is simple, you should specify the correct `area` where the element should be display, like this:

```css
grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 4;
```

As for a mindset, remember that when you're working with `CSS Grid` you are working in both directions `vertical` and `horizontal` or `columns` and `rows` like the `CSS Grid` specification. There are many good resources to learn `CSS Grid` like the [CSS Grid reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and this excellent [Scrimba course](https://scrimba.com/learn/R8PTE). Happy hacking!

Comment: Thank you sigfried!